# A doubt in Fulton and Harris regarding invariant subspace

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, invariant-subspace

This is a doubt in the section 3.3, Induced representations of F&H.

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ is a subgroup and $V$ is a representation of $G$ and $W \subset V$ is a subspace of $V$ which is $H$ invariant. Define $g\cdot W = \{ g\cdot w : w \in W\}$ for all $g \in G.$ Fulton and Harris argue that $g \cdot W$ depend only on the left coset $gH$ of $g$ modulo $H,$ since $$gh \cdot W = g\cdot(h \cdot W) = g \cdot W.$$
My doubt is that $W$ is an $H$ invariant, so $h \cdot W \subseteq W$ but equality is not necessary. Thus, shouldn't it be $$gh \cdot W \subseteq g\cdot W $$ rather than being equal?.
[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I have already written the content which is required to understand the question before attaching the image(Please see above the image). The image was attached for more clarity on question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of a group representation, the action of $h$ on $V$ is invertible, so $\dim (h\cdot W) = \dim W$.